# Link to specific tab WP with elegantTHEME divi

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, tabs

as a member of a local club which has its own website with one personal page per member I want to link to a specific tab on "our" personal page. The page is done with WP and uses the "divi"-theme from eleganttheme. On each page there are modules and one of them is a tabbed-content. In our case with 6 tabs. Going to a members page will show always the first tab. And now I want to know how to create a link that shows the 5th tab for example. I haven't found something in the web and the forum of elegantthemes is for customers only :-(
Would be great if I can get some ideas or instruction from here to create my proper link.

[Our personal page](http://www.commerces-pons.fr/hotel-de-bordeaux/)

Comment: read the divi theme wiki

Comment: To be confirm you want to show something in tab no 5 ?        like this one http://awesomescreenshot.com/0dd60n3c6e

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do.